How to Delete an Azure account?
I don't have any subscriptions and Azure is useless for me now. On top of that I'm using my personal email and somewhow it got linked to my School's directory. Pretty messed up.
I want to delete it but I didn't find anything in the documentation or in the settings.


Navigate to https://myaccount.microsoft.com/
Open Organizations
Click on Leave
Click on Why can't leave and/or reach out to support if the previous didn't help.



You’ll have to go into your Azure portal and find the subscriptions tab and either cancel or delete it in your portal.
If you still have trouble, post a screenshot of your subscriptions from your portal and can help from there.
